# How to choose an element, where I start writing?

Tags: javascript

I've made a function which adds a span element to the div. But when it's on-page and I want to write something inside it starts at this newly created span element and not inside the p element how it was before. How can I solve this problem?

```js
function addReply(clickingObjId, textArea, nickname) {
  let switchClick = document.getElementById(clickingObjId);
  let textBlock = document.getElementById(textArea);
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = `@${nickname}`;
  span.classList.add('reply-active');

  switchClick.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(textBlock);
    textBlock.appendChild(span);
  });
}
addReply("reply-button", "rep-content", "Nickname");
```

```css
.leave-comment {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
}

.content {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.reply-active {
  color: #378AD3;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" placeholder="Write your comment here" id="leave-com" class="leave-comment">
  <p class="content" id="rep-content"></p>
</div>
<p id="reply-button" class="reply-button">Reply</p>
```

Comment: Using the id assigned to the "p" tag (rep-content).  Add an input element and append it to the "p" tag.

Comment: I also found another way to do so (in case someone needs it). Use ```.prepend``` instead of ```.appendChild``` on div element and everything should be ok